# MAMP throwing error on Yii application - "Use of undefined constant home - assumed 'home'"

Tags: php, yii, model, localhost, mamp

I have a Yii app that I know the app has been working on a live environment. When I come to running it on a local environment I get the following error:

"Use of undefined constant home - assumed 'home'"

This is the code that is runnning before the error is thrown:

```
        if(isset($pageID)){
        $page = Page::model()->findByPk($pageID);
    } else {
        $url = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('action');
        if(isset($url)){
            $page = Page::model()->findByAttributes(array('url'=>$url));
        } else {
            $page = Page::model()->findByPk(2);
        }
    }
```

The line:

$page = Page::model()->findByPk(2);

... is highlighted in the stack trace. After commenting out everything aside from this line, the notice is still served. I suspect this means the problem is with model code Page.php.

It's a straight-forward bit of code that works on the live server no problem.

Yii is good at detailing it's errors and highlights the actual area that breaks:

```
/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(386)

  * }
  * </pre>
  *
  * @param string $className active record class name.
  * @return CActiveRecord active record model instance.
  */
 public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
 {
     if(isset(self::$_models[$className]))
         return self::$_models[$className];
     else
     {
         $model=self::$_models[$className]=new $className(null);
         $model->_md=new CActiveRecordMetaData($model);
         $model->attachBehaviors($model->behaviors());
         return $model;
     }
 }
```

I don't in all honesty understand what this error means or what's causing it. I've tried all sorts of things to rectify or further understand what's going wrong and I'm drawing a blank. It doesn't appear to be connectivity to the database (which has been correctly amended to local settings). .htaccess seems fine, mod-rewrite it turned on. The config.php file calls in the necessary models etc. Not sure where to go from here.

Why is this error being thrown and how do I go about fixing it?

**Update**

I've isolated the problem within model Page.php

The notice doesn't load after omit some contants such as:

```
const HOME=home;    
const ABOUT=about;
```

I assume that this didn't occur before because I was using an older version of MAMP or different php.ini setup.

Setting

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

within php.ini cleared the error.

Still left wondering why PHP doesn't like these constants defined in this way and what the correct way is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error (or, to be precise: this kind of notice) is most often the result of omitting `$` before a variable name. If there's `home` where `$home` should be, the interpreter treats it like a constant, but since such constant hasn't been previously defined, notice is thrown and string value assumed (`'home'` in this case).

The reason you're not getting the notice on your other machine is most likely due to notices being suppressed there.

The snipped you pasted doesn't look like it could be responsible for this (especially since it's from one of Yii classes); are you sure you're not pasting code from somewhere higher in the entire stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I really appreciate it, this is really stumping me. I can't find anything in the stack trace that isn't part of the Yii code. To ensure the Yii code isn't corrupt I've re-installed, but get the same error. I can't find 'home' anywhere in my code, it can only be from the Page active record id 2 that I'm calling. $page->url = 'home' for the record I'm calling with pk 2. Still puzzled :(

Comment: Line two in the stack trace reads: unknown(0): PageController->actionGateway(null)

Comment: I've now commented out everything apart from $page = Page::model()->findByPk(2); do you think this means that the problem is with the model?

Comment: I've isolated the problem within the Page model. It doesn't like some of the constants I've defined. I'll post above. Still don't understand why.

Comment: @goose Your constants aren't initialized properly. With `const HOME=home;` the interpreter sees constants on *both* sides of the `=` sign, so you're basically initializing one constant (`HOME`) with a value of another (`home` which is undefined, which is triggering a notice). What you probably meant was `const HOME='home';`

Comment: Thanks Lafor, I didn't realise that until now.